# How can I get rid of the "null pointer exception" while creating fragments dynamically?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to do to-do list application by using fragments. While creating this fragments dynamically, I take a null pointer exception at this line (in `mainactivity.java`):

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoItems);
listToDo.setListAdapter(adapter);
```

I cannot see this message on logcat: Log.w("6", "altı"); 
What is wrong with my code? How can I solve this problem?

The `activity_main.xml` file:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:orientation="vertical">


   <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/list_view_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        >    </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

to_do_fragment.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/add_to_do_fragment" >  
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/addButton"
        android:contentDescription="@string/addItemContentDescription"
        android:text="@string/add_button"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/addButton"
        android:hint="@string/edit_text" />   
    </RelativeLayout>

list_view.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list_view" >
    <ListView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"></ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>


LogCat

    10-30 19:28:26.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1763): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    10-30 19:28:26.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1763): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.todolistwithdynamicfragments/com.example.todolistwithdynamicfragments.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080003 (com.example.todolistwithdynamicfragments:id/add_to_do_fragment) for fragment AddToDoFragment{41770868 #0 id=0x7f080003}
    10-30 19:28:26.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
    10-30 19:28:26.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
    10-30 19:28:26.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    10-30 19:28:26.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
    10-30 19:28:26.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    10-30 19:28:26.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    10-30 19:28:26.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    10-30 19:28:26.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    10-30 19:28:26.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    10-30 19:28:26.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    10-30 19:28:26.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    10-30 19:28:26.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    10-30 19:28:26.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1763): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080003 (com.example.todolistwithdynamicfragments:id/add_to_do_fragment) for fragment AddToDoFragment{41770868 #0 id=0x7f080003}
    10-30 19:28:26.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:877)
    10-30 19:28:26.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
    10-30 19:28:26.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
    10-30 19:28:26.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
    10-30 19:28:26.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5142)
    10-30 19:28:26.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
    10-30 19:28:26.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1763):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: NullPointerExceptions are easy to track down.  You need to post your logcat output for us to help you.

Comment: What code is at MainActivity.java line 41 ?

Comment: @AakashGoyal - its pointed out right at the top of the question....

Comment: listToDo.setListAdapter(adapter);

Comment: @cgbs the id list_view_fragment is for a FrameLayout and you are casting it to a ToDoListFragment, can that be the issue ?

Comment: @dymmeh Yes I saw the two lines but was asking which one is on 41 :)

Comment: @AakashGoyal - the adapter initialization won't throw a NPE if todoItems is null so it was easy to figure out which one it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move this line

`listToDo = (ToDoListFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.list_view_fragment);`

into your else statement.

You are essentially nulling out `listToDo` on your first run since the fragment manager will not find your fragment that you just committed. `commit()` schedules your fragments to be added. It does not mean they are added right away. So, calling `findFragmentById` will return null when you call it immediately after which is why `listToDo` ends up null.

Comment: But ı think null pointer exeption is gone.
I edited the log cat again

Comment: @cgbs - Your fragment expects your Activity to implement your listener. Change your activity declaration to "public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AddToDoFragment.OnToDoAddedListener" . You already have the method in the activity for the interface so you just need to change the activity to implement the interface.

Comment: glad to help :) enjoy!

Comment: Would you mind if I ask you one more question? I used frame layout and so my first fragment which consists of one edittext and one button appears two times over and over. How can i provide it to be shown just one times?

Comment: You are inflating your activity_main.xml view in your fragment as well as in your main activity. You should have a separate view created for your fragment that only contains the button and edit text. Then in activity_main you can remove the button and edit text within your FrameLayout since they now exist in your separate fragment's layout. Same with your list fragment.

Comment: I tried it but this time i face with another error, i edited my question, new xml files are edited and i also edit the logcat message.

Comment: It looks like you removed the <FrameLayout for your add_to_do_list in activity_main . You still need the framelayout to hold the fragment. You just don't need the stuff that was inside of the framelayout

Comment: i don't think i understand you

Comment: In activity_main you should have a frame layout for each of your fragments. The xml you posted only has a FrameLayout for your ToDoListFragment and not your AddToDoFragment.

Answer (score 0):

Your toDoItems is not getting initialized in the following line:

```
todoItems = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("todoItemTag");
```

I would suggest you test the array to ensure that it is not null.  Something like:

```
Log.i("ARRAY",todoItems.length);
```

Comment: Based on the way he is initializing/saving/restoring the list this will never be null.

Answer (score 0):

Since `todoItems` is the only one of the three parameters in that line that could be null, that must be the culprit. The only way I see for it to be null is if the `savedInstanceState` does not include `"todoItemTag"` which could easily happen under many scenarios. Your code is assuming that the `savedInstanceState` always has `"todoItemTag"` if `savedInstanceState` is not null, but it very well could be non-null and have nothing in it. I would rewrite your code sort of like this, but actually I don't understand why you are only creating the fragment under certain circumstances, so this probably needs more work:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

if (savedInstanceState!=null)
    todoItems = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("todoItemTag");

if (todoItems == null) {
    todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();
}

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoItems);
listToDo.setListAdapter(adapter);

//TODO fragment management

}
```